# Mysql Trigger throwing 'TRIGGER command denied to user'

Tags: mysql, triggers, permissions

Im trying to create a basic test trigger (code below) when I run this statement I get a 'TRIGGER command denied to user' error. I have tried to GRANT the permissions but that also threw an error stating that I didn't have permissions.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger  
AFTER INSERT ON `membershipType` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO test (mName) VALUES (NEW.name);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Can somebody advise if there is anything wrong with the above statement or if the problem is down to permissions with my host.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is fine.  It is likely an issue with the permissions allotted to the account you are using.  If you are using a hosting provider this is highly likely.